# Find k such that the following matrix M is singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$M=\begin{pmatrix}4&-4&2\\-8&7&-6\\-30+k&22&-16\end{pmatrix}.$$
I have to find $k$ such that $A$ be singular. I keep getting $-6$ but its marked incorrect.

Comment: It's $6$, not $-6$. Check your sign. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+%5B%5B+4%2C+-4%2C+2+%5D%2C+%5B-8%2C+7%2C+-6%5D%2C+%5B-30%2Bk%2C+22%2C+-16%5D%5D)

Comment: ^Appreciate it!